# Using ReentrantLock instead of synchronized for improving performance

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I'm trying to find the most optimal solution for my particular situation.

I currently have the following class:

```
public class Container

    private volatile Date date;
    private int amount;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void update(int amount){
        int actualAmount;
        if(check(date)){
              //do some BULK computation to compute the actualAmount
             synchronized(lock){
                 date = new Date();
                 this.amount = actualAmount;
             }
        }
    }

    private boolean check(Date date){
        synchronized(lock){
          //reading from the date and returning true if the date is expired
        }
    }
}
```

The class represents all updates of amount of money shared by a user group. The group may consist up to 100 users. The `amount` field may be updated by any user of the group concurrently.

Calling the `update(int)` includes entering two synchronized blocks which is not very good from performance standpoint. Also it may happen that the BULK operation will be computed twice or more times even if there is no need for it. Actually, assume that three threads are trying to acces `update()` concurrently. The `check(date)` returned true in each of the threads. It doesn't do any harm, but the **BULK** operation is quite heavy (more thaqn 1 minute). So, it's critical to not perform it even twice if there is no need.

It's not possible to wrap the **BULK** operation into a synchronized block becuase it includes calling a couple of alien methods. So, I tend to use `ReentrantLock` instead of synchronization. The class then may be rewritten as follows:

```
public class Container

    private volatile Date date;
    private int amount;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void update(int amount){
        int actualAmount;
        lock.lock();
        try{
            if(check(date)){
                 //do some BULK computation to compute the actualAmount
                 date = new Date();
                 this.amount = actualAmount;
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private boolean check(Date date){
         //reading from the date and returning true if the date is expired
    }
}
```

***QUESTION:*** Is such using of `ReentrantLock` more efficient in such circumstances than explicit `synchronization`.

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible to use a synchronized block?  Your `update()` method locks a lock, then it does some stuff, and then it unlocks the lock.  How is that any different from doing some stuff inside a `synchronized` block?

Comment: @jameslarge Because I don't know for sure what kind of staff the the BULK-computation does.

Comment: So?  Your `update()` method locks a lock, it does some stuff, and then it insures that the lock will be unlocked before returning.  A `synchronized` block does exactly the same thing:  It locks a lock, it does some stuff, and then it insures that the lock will be unlocked.  It doesn't matter what the "stuff" is in either case.

Comment: in the method void update(int amount), if(check(date))==false, value of the amount parameter is lost. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same without synchronization.

Synchronization is needed only if a thread needs to know the value of a variable to update it. If the thread only change a variable it is sufficient to define it as volatile.

```
public class Container

    private volatile Date date;
    private volatile int amount;

    public void update(int amount){
        int actualAmount;
        if (check(date)) {
              //do some BULK computation to compute the actualAmount

             date = new Date();
             this.amount = actualAmount;
        }
    }

    private boolean check(Date date) {

          //reading from the date and returning true if the date is expired
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** A synchronization can be necessary if the amount depends on the actual amount value. A synchronization for date is not necessary

Comment: But, what if other threads invoke the method while the bulk operation is still in progress?

Comment: The comment "do some BULK computation" represents code that probably needs to know the values of one or more variables in order to update them.

Comment: @James I added the info in the note to show exactly that. Note that it is possible that actualAmount doesn't depends on the value of amount.

Comment: But it's not just about `this.amount`  We don't know what "do some BULK computation" means.  If the question is, "Is this code thread safe without synchronization?" then we have to assume the answer is no unless we can see _everything_ that it does.

Comment: As clearely explained in the note. The synchronization can be necessary if in the amount depends on the actual amount value.